# How do you run Chrome while selenium headless script is executing on mac?

Tags: python, macos, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have a python selenium script that uses chromedriver in headless mode to test links on a website. I'm running this script on MacOS High Sierra.

If I have Chrome open prior to running the script, I can continue to use the browser normally.  Headless mode appears to isolate me from the testing.  However, if Chrome is closed first, I cannot launch the browser while the selenium script is running.

Looking at Activity monitor in the first scenario, it appears to me that chromedriver creates a new process for Chrome to run.  So I (perhaps incorrectly) assumed I should be able to launch the browser manually while the script is running.

[image]

What am I missing?
**How do I launch Chrome while selenium is running on Mac?**

Comment: Selenium should open a new Chrome window when it's running, but I don't believe it should prevent you from also using Chrome.

Comment: I didn't think so either.  Nevertheless clicking on chrome while the selenium is running does nothing.

Comment: Does cmd+N not open a new window?

Comment: I can't use cmd+N because do not actually see Chrome open when selenium is in headless mode.

Comment: You will need to update your question to make it reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah-HA!
This [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/277629/275313) I stumbled upon made it possible to open Chrome while selenium is running (although I don't understand why it works one way but not the other).

> For most applications, launching with `open -naF "App Name"` or `open -nF
>   /path/to/application.app` should be sufficient (see Safari, Forklift,
>   Office apps, etc.).
>
> - `-n` opens a new instance
> - `-a` tells open to look in the list of registered apps (no need to specify the full path, but can go wrong if you have multiple versions
>     of an app. I sometimes see issues on my system with differentiating
>     between macOS apps and apps installed by Parallels OSes… I prefer to
>     specify the path directly.)
> - `-F` opens a fresh instance (ignores an app save state left over from previous instances)